# Compute the limit of $\frac{\left(1^a+3^a+\dots+(2n+1)^a\right)^{b+1}}{\left(2^b+4^b+\dots+(2n)^b\right)^{a+1}}$ when $n\to+\infty$

Tags: real-analysis

> Calculate
>   $$
> \lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{\left(1^a+3^a+\dots+(2n+1)^a\right)^{b+1}}{\left(2^b+4^b+\dots+(2n)^b\right)^{a+1}} \quad a,b\neq 0
> $$

My attempt:
I want to use integral way to solve it, hence I rewritten the equation into 
$$
\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{\left(\left({1\over 2n+1}\right)^a+\left({3\over 2n+1}\right)^a+\dots+\left({2n+1\over 2n+1}\right)^a\right)^{b+1}}{\left({2\over 2n}^b+{4\over 2n}^b+\dots+\left({2n\over 2n}\right)^b\right)^{a+1}}=\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{(2n+1)^{ab+a}}{(2n)^{ab+b}}\frac{\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\left({2k+1\over2n+1}\right)^a{2\over 2n+1}{2n+1\over 2}\right)^{b+1}}{\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\left({2k\over2n}\right)^b{2\over 2n}{2n\over 2}\right)^{a+1}}.
$$
$$
\lim_{n\to+\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\left({2k+1\over2n+1}\right)^a{2\over 2n+1}=\int_0^1x^a\mathrm{d}x={1\over a+1}.
$$
$$
\lim_{n\to+\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\left({2k\over2n}\right)^a{2\over 2n}=\int_0^1x^b\mathrm{d}x={1\over b+1}.
$$
Then I get 
$$
\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{\left({1\over a+1}{2n+1\over 2}\right)^{b+1}}{\left({1\over b+1}{2n\over 2}\right)^{a+1}}\frac{(2n+1)^{ab+a}}{(2n)^{ab+b}}.
$$
It can be written as
$$
\lim_{n\to+\infty} \frac{({1\over 2a+2})^{b+1}}{({1\over 2b+2})^{a+1}}\left(\frac{2n+1}{2n}\right)^{(a+1)(b+1)}=\frac{({1\over 2a+2})^{b+1}}{({1\over 2b+2})^{a+1}} .
$$
In my original calculation,under the remind of the comment by Did, I missed the index $b+1$ and $a+1$ with $b$ and $a$, hence could not offset the $2n+1$ and $2n$ term. Now I think the question has been solved correctly.

Comment: You forgot to copy some factors of the Riemann sums and miscopied some exponents. If you correct these, you are left with $$\frac{\left({1\over a+1}{2n+1\over 2}(2n+1)^a\right)^{b+1}}{\left({1\over b+1}{2n\over 2}(2n)^b\right)^{a+1}}$$ which simplifies nicely into $$\frac{2^{a+1}(b+1)^{a+1}(2n+1)^{(a+1)(b+1)}}{2^{b+1}(a+1)^{b+1}(2n)^{(a+1)(b+1)}}$$ Can you finish this?

Comment: @Did Thank you, I  made lots of mistakes, I would corrected it,